# Can association table be in a relationship with other tables

Tags: sql, database, relationship, entity-relationship

Forgive me for this perhaps trivial question, but I could not find an answer to it.
Let's assume the situation goes like this:
I have tables:
Team - can have multiple members
Member - can have multiple teams
and now suppose I want to have a "Task" table, I want this task to be assigned to a member(or several) only within a given team. And here comes my question, Can I make a "Task" table which should be in a relationship with the associative table Team_Member, or is this not recommended? Or is there any better way to do this.
Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Hi @Matt.k, Can you tell me how do you create the relationship between Task and Team_Member.TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make a "Task" table which should be in a relationship with the associative table Team_Member.

Sure.  There's nothing unusual about that from a relational modeling point-of-view.  And that ensures that the Task doesn't just belong to a valid User and a valid Team, but that the Task's User is (still) a member of the Task's Team.

Comment: Exactly as I thought, thanks for the help.